# Диагностика компьютера - зависание

Tags: железо, hdd, ram, видеокарта, видеодрайвера

Помогите продиагностировать компьютер.

Время от времени при работе на компьютере он начинает зависать - перестаёт двигаться мышка и работать клавиатура (в общем не откликается ни на какие действия), помогает только перезагрузка, при том, что, если это случилось при разговоре в скайпе, скайп продолжает работать и я могу разговаривать, но ничего больше. Что может быть источником этого и как точно узнать. Когда-то диагностировал жёсткий диск и обнаружил, что в нём много битых секторов, может ли это быть причиной и как убедится, что это именно он или что-либо другое?

Comment: Включить логирование и почитать лог файл, сразу станет ясно что именно становится причиной. Если лень читать лог файл - перефирия(USB\клава\мышка...) висит вместе с винчестером на чипсете. Так что да, отвал перефирии - часто вызван винтом\перегрузкой чипа(перегревом).

Comment: Спасибо, а как включить логирование и где лог файл?